# Array rellenado por teclado

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo los Arrays, y me ha surgido un problema, es rellenar por teclado un array de enteros y sumar el total de esos números. La verdad que he estado buscando información pero no encuentro exactamente como hacer esa operación, si alguien tiene un enlace a un foro me pueda decir como se hace se lo agradecería.

añado lo que llevaba de codigo:

```
package boletinArrays;
import static boletinExpresiones.Teclado.*;
public class EjerciciosArrays {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ej01();

}

/*
 * 1.- Pedir datos al usuario
 *  1.1.- Pedir tamaño del array
 *  1.2.- Pedir tantos numeros de enteros como el tamaño
 * 2.- Suma todos los arrays
 * 3.- Devolver resultados
 */
public static int ej01() {
    int sum = 0,p;
    String x;
    String s,n;
    x=readString("Dame un numero: ");
    int num[]=new int[Integer.parseInt(x)];
        System.out.println(num);

    //1.- Pedir datos al usuario
    //1.1.- Pedir tamaño del array
    return sum;
```

**`readString` es una clase donde tengo todos los usos del teclado controlados**

Comment: Que llevas hecho hasta ahora , para poder ayudarte?

Comment: El sitio no esta estructurado para eso. Aca haces una pregunta y recibis una respuesta. Lo que estas preguntando, no tiene una respuesta. tiene montones. Si intentas algo, podemos ayudarte a ir corrigiendolo...

Comment: He editado, para que veáis lo que llevaba, aun no he logrado sacar la conclusion me he atascado bastante en esta tontería.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ver te he comentado todo el codigo de como lo realizaría yo, si no entiendes algo me lo dices!

```js
package ex02;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner lec = new Scanner(System.in);
  int arraySize; //Variable para el tamaño de la array
  int sumaTotal=0;
  
  /*
   * 1.- Pedir datos al usuario
   *  1.1.- Pedir tamaño del array
   *  1.2.- Pedir tantos numeros de enteros como el tamaño
   * 2.- Suma todos los arrays
   * 3.- Devolver resultados
   */
  System.out.println("Start"); //Arranca el programa
  
  System.out.println("Introduce el tamaño de la array:");
  arraySize=lec.nextInt(); // Guardamos el tamaño de la array
  
  int array[]= new int[arraySize]; //Definimos la array con la variable del tamaño
  
  System.out.println("Procedemos a rellenar la array");
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   array[i]=lec.nextInt();  //Guardamos cada valor en su posicion
   sumaTotal+=array[i];  //Sumamos todos los valores
   
  }
  
  
  System.out.println("Suma:"+ sumaTotal); // Printamos tamaño total
  

 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he entendido perfectamente.Solo que este trozo `System.out.println("Start"); //Arranca el programa` para mi sobraría pero es una costumbre supongo así que perfecto.